# Find next largest element using index in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, indexing, return-value

I have list `A = [China, India, France, Italy]` and list `B = [2000, 3000, 3500, 1000]`.

I use code :

```
B_desc = sorted(B, reverse=True)
max_B = max(B_desc)
idx_max = B.index(max_B)
first_country = A[idx_max]
```

to find country which corresponds to largest value but not sure how to use index to find country with second largest value.
Is it possible to loop for finding 4 or more countries with largest  values?

Comment: As you sort B the max is just `B_desc[0]`, second max is `B_desc[1]`

Comment: @azro thx solution is good enough. What if I want to compare with a value and loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but may break if len(A) != len(B)

```
A = 'China, India, France, Italy'.split(', ')
B = [2000, 3000, 3500, 1000]

C = {a:B[i] for i,a in enumerate(A)}
sort = sorted(C.keys(),key=C.get,reverse=True)

first = sort[0]
second = sort[1]
# etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use `zip` to build pairs, then sort in reverse on the `int` value

```
A = ["China", "India", "France", "Italy"]
B = [2000, 3000, 3500, 1000]

values = sorted(zip(A, B), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

>>print("Max pair", values[0])
Max pair ('France', 3500)

>>print("Second max pair", values[1])
Second max pair ('India', 3000)
```